# Errors on hex characters and hash

Tags: c#, hex

I have a project that is almost near completion aside from a couple of stubborn but probably simple error Im receiving. I am by know means knowledgeable of C and me getting this project this far is a miracle. Im hoping someone can detect what it is I am missing in my code. [Here](http://gyazo.com/e2ce632a3876a7114cebfa0e666cafa1)  is the view of the errors and below is the code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        StringBuilder bin = new StringBuilder();
        int buf = 0;
        int bufLen = 0;
        int left = 53;
        for (int i = 106; i >= 1; i += -1)
        {
            buf <<= 1;
            if (rnd.Next(i) < left)
            {
                buf += 1;
                left -= 1;
            }
            bufLen += 1;
            if (bufLen == 4)
            {
                bin.Append("0123456789ABCDEF"(buf));
                bufLen = 0;
                buf = 0;
            }
        }
        string b = bin.ToString();
        bin.Append("048c"(buf));


        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed m = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed();
        byte[] hash = m.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(b));

        //replace first two bits in hash with bits from buf
        hash(0) = Convert.ToByte(hash(0) & 0x3f | (buf * 64));
        //append 24 bits from hash
        b = b.Substring(0, 26) + BitConverter.ToString(hash, 0, 3).Replace("-", string.Empty);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is this Java and not C++?

Comment: Please include the error messages directly rather than through an html link.

Comment: @EdHeal I think it's C# actually

Comment: C++ doesn't have a `StringBuilder` class unless the OP wrote their own.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct syntax for C++: `bin.Append("0123456789ABCDEF"(buf));`.  My issue is that the compiler only concatenates string literals, not string literals to string variables.  It also looks like a possible function call within call to `Append`.

Comment: Definitely C# (`(object sender, EventArgs e)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x(y)` means "call `x` with `y` as a parameter".

You have written `"0123456789ABCDEF"(buf)`. `"0123456789ABCDEF"` isn't a function (or a functor) so you can't call it.

Perhaps you meant to index it, with `"0123456789ABCDEF"[buf]`? This returns the `buf`'th character from "0123456789ABCDEF", which is `buf` in hexadecimal as long as `buf` is between 0 and 15.

Comment: Thank you @immibis, now just to fix the two hash errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate a string literal with a string variable.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

void concatenate(const std::string& s)
{
    cout << "In concatenate, string passed is: "
         << s
         << "\n";
}

int main(void)
{
    std::string world = " World!\n";
    concatenate("Hello"(world));
    return 0;
}

Thomas@HastaLaVista ~/concatenation
# g++ -o main.exe main.cpp
main.cpp: In function `int main()':
**main.cpp:15: error: `"Hello"' cannot be used as a function**

Thomas@HastaLaVista ~/concatenation
# g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

You will need a temporary string variable:

```
if (bufLen == 4)
{
   std::string temp("01234567890ABCDEF");
   temp += buf;
   bin.Append(temp);
   bufLen = 0;
   buf = 0;
}
```